# How to check if the declaration is 'extern' in GCC GENERIC?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, internals

I'm playing with GCC IR and I want to check if the declaration was `extern` in C source:

```
extern int i;
```

I want to do that on GENERIC tree, to get something like this (by analogy to `TREE_STATIC` macro):

```
tree t;
if (TREE_EXTERN (t))
   // do handling of extern
```

I've checked the GCC Internals [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/), but didn't find the needed function or macro.

Comment: I cannot conceive of any good reason why it matters to your code if a variable is in another object file or not.  By the time its running, its all in the same process.   Please explain *why* you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on GCC internals, but perhaps `DECL_EXTERNAL` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks.
By the way, how did you find it? GCC Internals' documentation is pretty poor and unsearchable.

Comment: I searched the source of the C frontend for "extern", that's how I found it. Then I read its definition and related comment in `tree.h` and realized that it's likely to be what you need.